# Match Timestamp with regex expression

Tags: regex

I would like to match timestamps in the following format `[12/Jun/2013:06:31:31 -0700]` in a log file.

What Regex expression shoud I use ? Thanks

Comment: Please try something, I'm begging you !

Comment: Try `\[../.../....:..:..:.. -....\]` It will probably do the job

Comment: @AdrianPronk you forgot '+': `\[../.../....:..:..:.. [-+]....\]`

Comment: @Cœur: I was guessing that OP's log file would only have the one time-zone (or maybe two for summer time). And I didn't want to spoon-feed the answer entirely.

Comment: @HamZa I tried \[\d{2}\/[A-Z][a-z]{2}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -0700\]   but can't get it to work

Comment: @user2485577 Good boy, now I;ll help ya `\[\d{2}\/[A-Z][a-z]{2}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{1,4}\]`. Have fun :)

Comment: @user2485577 You need to escape the square brackets with a brackslash, so that you have `\[` and `\]`. Next, the `[a-z]{3}` should be `[a-z]{2}`.

Comment: @HamZa What if the OP's a girl? O.o

Comment: @Jerry lolz, awkward moment :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep -E '\[[0-9]{2}/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.*\]' <<<"[12/Jun/2013:06:31:31 -0700]"
```

But this will only match the string in the described format.

You will probably need to check if that date is correct. Because the string

```
"[94/Non/2084:54:71:99 +9999]"
```

will be matched with this regexp as well.

Of course you can make a regexp with date validation, but the regexp will be like 3 times longer.

Consider using python date and time libs for checking the valid format.

You can also use unix `date` program

```
date -d "now" "+[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]"
```

will print the format you want of the date now.

Obviously `date -d` needs the correct specific input, so you need to adjust that input and then call date

```
proper=`date -d "12/01/2013 06:31:31" "+[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]"`
```

And then you can compare it (warning: the timezone output will be yours tz)

```
[[ "[12/Jun/2013:06:31:31 -0700]" == "$proper" ]] && echo ok
```

Because of the adjusting and forking date, this isn't good way. So use python if the checking is needed :)

The checking function in python will look something like this small example

```
def isTimeFormat(input,timeformat):

try:
    # Parse input to timeformat
    time.strptime(input, timeformat)
    # It was OK, no exception raised
    return True
# if there is an extra data or string cannot be parsed according to format, exception is raised
except ValueError:
    return False
```

Finally, when you checked your input with regex, you can compare it easily in python

```
withTZ="[12/Jun/2013:06:31:31 -0700]" 
withoutTZ=withTZ[0:21]+withTZ[27:] 
if isTimeFormat(withoutTZ,"[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S]"):
  print("OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is just to fetch the timestamps from the log file, you likely don't need any validation, so just use this regex:

```
\[\d{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [+-]\d{4}\]
```